# SQL - How do you aggregate a field based on another field

Tags: sql

I'd like to get the average of all the records in FieldA where FieldB is equal to 'a'

Any help would be great thanks

Table Example:

```
FieldA  FieldB
100     a
200     b
233     a
432     a
643     a
234     b
123     a
321     a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT AVG(FieldA) as Average FROM Table1
WHERE FieldB='a'
```

The result will be:

```
AVERAGE
308
```

See the result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/54b12/1)

`AVG()` returns the average of the values in a group. Null values are ignored.

Syntax:

```
AVG ( [ ALL | DISTINCT ] expression )
```

Read more about `AVG()` [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try this.You can use [**AVG**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx)

```
SELECT AVG(FieldA) AS Average
FROM tablename
WHERE FieldB='a'
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6289a/1)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT Avg(FieldA) AS Average
FROM Table1
WHERE FieldB = 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select avg(fieldA)
from table_name
where fieldB='a';
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/54b12/4)